# How to write 1.0 in InputFields with ContinuousAction and Number constraint

Tags: dynamic, cdf-format, gui-construction, inputfield

With the concept of **user responsiveness** in mind, I’ve tinkered a couple of small apps that are supposed to be eh… responsive, i.e. calculating without having to press enter.
They all rely on `InputField` with `ContinuousAction` and shall only accept numbers and decimal points.

Code snippet as an example:

```
field1 = 1;
Grid[{{"Input a number"}, {InputField[Dynamic[field1, (field1 = #) &],
     Number, ContinuousAction -> True]}}]
```

Everything works except when trying to write `1.01` since it halts at the lonely zero which isn’t considered a `Number`.
[image]
**Question:**
So my question is, how to make `InputField` accept a lonely zero after the decimal point as a number while continually evaluating the users every keystroke.

**Edit:**
The final goal is to get a quick and responsive CDF. I believe true `ContinuousAction` will open up for a lot of small useful applications.

Comment: There is somewhere closely related question. Current behaviour is quite poor. Specially in .CDF context when only `Number` fields are allowed. If you are not going to put it in CDF I'd work with strings

Comment: @Kuba Yes I asked a compound question where this problem was mentioned. But since I haven't solved it yet, I tried to chisel out a new and hopefully clearer question :)

Comment: @Kuba Any trick up your sleeve as to achieve the same effect? I have these old programs I wrote in Flash ActionScript that are extremely responsive. I would very much like to rewrite them in Mathematica.

Comment: Why not use `Expression` instead of `Number`. While you could use `String` you will need to convert to be able to use the string number.

Comment: @kuba zero after the decimal not being accepted looks like a bug. What do u think?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I think so.

Comment: MathLind, could you just add a small example what should be done in (filed=#)&?

Comment: @Kuba, You could check my A to the earlier Q you helped me answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70009/inputfield-as-both-in-and-output-fields-with-continuousaction since I don't have access to Mathematica here at work.

Comment: The problem is that with `ContinuousAction -> True` is that the input `1.0` is immediately converted to a number and displayed, the number being the real number one.  The number one is displayed automatically as `1.`, which removes the `0` from the `InputField`.  I seriously doubt there is a way to hack `InputField` in a way that it will work in CDF (or that there is any way at all). - [Should this be an answer?]

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. Yes I allude  to the probable reason behind this behavior in my question. I have also consulted WR and got the answer that this isn't possible to fix i a manner I would prefer. Anyway I believe the responsiveness would be highly desirable. ["...answer?"], Yes why not, it would certainly help the reader.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just stumbled upon some faulty or at least not fully funtional code in the documentation under DynamicModule/Examples/Applications Try the first example "input a number". Remarkable that they haven't notices.

Comment: Yes, remarkable!

Comment: @MichaelE2 it's hanging here so long I think you comment is a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

From my comment:

The problem is that with `ContinuousAction -> True` is that the input `1.0` is immediately converted to a number and displayed, the number being the real number one. The number one is displayed automatically as `1.`, which removes the `0` from the InputField. I seriously doubt there is a way to hack `InputField` in a way that it will work in CDF.  One needs access to the input string (or an equivalent), but only numbers are disallowed; see https://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/details-for-mathematica-programmers.html.

Comment: And in FreePlayer only `Numeric` number field is available. :)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks.  I added a link to a (current) reference for the limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
Grid[{{"Input a number"}, {InputField[
    Dynamic[field1, If[NumberQ[#], field1 = #, field1 = Null] &], 
    Expression, ContinuousAction -> True]}}]
```

Comment: @Kuba Why? ....

Comment: @Kuba the OP makes no mention of CDF

Comment: Ahh, there was a comment from OP that the final goal is CDF, I don't know why he deleted it.

Comment: @Kuba ok, well I'll leave the question for now and delete it if he confirms he wants to deploy in CDF

Comment: @Kuba actually I'll be away the rest of the week so will make it a community wiki then anyone can delete ...right?

Comment: I don't know. But leave it. If someone complain I will flag his comments!

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I edited my Q to clarify. Yes CDF is the goal. And yes, I cleaned up what a thought was a chatty thread of comments :) I will check your A later today, thanks.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, No unfortunately your A seems to need an <enter> to evaluate. My poor example evaluates at the moment the user hits the key... but can't accept a lonely zero after the decimal point.